# How to interact with a windows GUI through CLI to use custom parameters/arguments?

Tags: windows, user-interface, parameters, command-line-interface

I have a windows native application that I'm porting to a web based service and have no access to the code.

The windows application requires the user to input an executable file (into the windows application) then set parameters through it via the GUI (such as check-boxes) and obtain a different output based on the new parameters the windows application has set.

1. User uploads Bob.exe via website with parameters
2. Website pushes that to windows back-end with parameters
3. Windows server processes the request (and Bob.exe) with the new parameters)
4. Windows server uploads new, modified Bob.exe to front web UI.
5. Completed.

The native windows application has no CLI functionality and it requires GUI interaction to set the parameters. **We need to automate this function.** in order to port the native windows application to a web based service.

How do we archive this? I did quite a bit of research and came up with nothing!

Thank you stackoverflow.

Comment: What do you mean by "_and obtain a different output based on the new parameters the windows application has set_"? Different than what? What kind of output?

Comment: The windows application modifies the input and outputs a different output to the input it initially received. The output is a modified executable file, the input is an executable file. The windows app handles all that, we just need to have the ability to automate that to a web UI and we're having trouble doing that.

Comment: Are the input and output names of executables? Or the actual binaries in the form of files? How is the output produced? In an Edit box? In a label shown somewhere in a form? As a file? In a logfile? Perhaps you could include screenshots of the application to illustrate the problem and what you want?

Comment: The input name would be unique and the output name would be unique (we thought of doing that so a separate script can more easily serve the new output to the user based on the unique .exe output name), the native windows application literally modifies the entire executable (input) and it outputs a new executable (output) I can't disclose what modifications are made to the executable. No labels are shown, the windows app after making modifications pops up with a new window for where the user would like to save the new output .exe

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is installing a VNC server on the windows computer, and use ruby-vnc from your web server to connect and control input. You would ideally rely purely on keystrokes, but you can also control the pointer if needed. [See this article](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2010/08/29/sending-keystrokes-to-your-virtual-machines-using-X-vnc-rdp-or-native/) for reference.